# Can't get balance of ALICE account from RPC via curl

Tags: polkadot, json-rpc

If run this RPC query via curl:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "state_getStorage", "params": ["0xc2261276cc9d1f8598ea4b6a74b15c2fb99d880ec681799c0cf30e8886371da9de1e86a9a8c739864cf3cc5ec2bea59fd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d"]}' http://127.0.0.1:9933
```

The output is null when it should display the balance of the ALICE account.  WHY?

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":null,"id":1}
```

[image: Polkadot UI]

Comment: I'm trying to use the examples in:  https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate/querying-substrate-storage-via-rpc.  I can't get the storage map query to work either.  Why?

Comment: The article mentions storage value `Balances::FreeBalance`, it was probably how balances were formerly handled. The answer below from Lana explains the new way of getting the free balance.

Comment: ^^^ Does this mean that it is impossible to get the balance with a simple request? I can't add comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `substrate-node-template` allows you to query the `system.account` storage item, see screenshot [image]

The corresponding command is

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "state_getStorage", "params": ["0x26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef7b99d880ec681799c0cf30e8886371da9de1e86a9a8c739864cf3cc5ec2bea59fd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d"]}' http://127.0.0.1:9933

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x01000000000000000100000000000000dcb114568172fc0f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","id":1}
```

The `frame_system` declares an `AccountInfo` struct that [details](https://docs.rs/frame-system/latest/src/frame_system/lib.rs.html#744) the data field of an account:

```
/// Information of an account.
#[derive(Clone, Eq, PartialEq, Default, RuntimeDebug, Encode, Decode)]
pub struct AccountInfo<Index, AccountData> {
    /// The number of transactions this account has sent.
    pub nonce: Index,
    /// The number of other modules that currently depend on this account's existence. The account
    /// cannot be reaped until this is zero.
    pub consumers: RefCount,
    /// The number of other modules that allow this account to exist. The account may not be reaped
    /// until this is zero.
    pub providers: RefCount,
    /// The additional data that belongs to this account. Used to store the balance(s) in a lot of
    /// chains.
    pub data: AccountData,
}
```

The `runtime/src/lib.rs` is where all of your configs are created. If you look carefully at

```
impl frame_system::Config for Runtime {
    ...
    type AccountData = pallet_balances::AccountData<Balance>;
    ...
}
```

and

```
impl pallet_balances::Config for Runtime {
    ...
    type AccountStore = System;
    ...

}
```

you will see why the `system` storage exposes the balances in the data, not the `balances` storage. Use `type AccountStore = Balances;` instead to leverage the usage of `pallet-balances`.

Comment: ...THAT'S WHY! :)